# Loading XML data into JavaScript and changing div colors with the XML data

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

This is homework question requiring that I use color information collected in a XML file to change the color of twenty divs with a button.  I have approached this by creating a single class of divs in the html document, loading the XML data into a Javascript file and iterating through the XML.  I think the problem is that I am incorrectly loading the XML document into Javascript? I posted sections of the code as follows (I only posted one part of the css so it wouldn't be so long)

```
<div class="div" id="two"><h2>2</h2></div>    
<div class="div" id="one"><h1>1<br><br> <br>REQUIREMENT #1</h1></div>
<div class="div" id="three"><h2>3</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="four"><h2>4</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="five"><h2>5</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="six"><h2>6</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="seven"><h2>7</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="eight"><h2>8</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="nine"><h2>9</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="ten"><h2>10</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="eleven"><h2>11</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="twelve"><h2>12</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="thirteen"><h2>13</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="fourteen"><h2>14</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="fifteen"><h2>15</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="sixteen"><h2>16</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="seventeen"><h2>17</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="eighteen"><h2>18</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="nineteen"><h2>19</h2></div>
<div class="div" id="twenty"><h2>20</h2></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="changediv" onclick="changeColors()">


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<divcolors>
<div name ="one">
<color>aliceblue</color>
</div>
<div name ="two">
<color>aquamarine</color>
</div>
<div name="three">
<color>coral</color>
</div>
<div name="four">
<color>cornflowerblue</color>
</div>
<div name="five">
<color>cyan</color>
</div>
<div name="six">
<color>darkgray</color>
</div>
<div name="seven">
<color>darkolivegreen</color>
</div>
<div name="eight">
<color>darkviolet</color>
</div>
<div name="nine">
<color>deepskyblue</color>
</div>
<div name="ten">
<color>forestgreen</color>
</div>
<div name="eleven">
<color>honeydew</color>
</div>
<div name="twelve">
<color>lightsalmon</color>
</div>
<div name="thirteen">
<color>lightsteelblue</color>
</div>
<div name="fourteen">
<color>maroon</color>
</div>
<div name="fifteen">
<color>mediumspringgreen</color>
</div>
<div name="sixteen">
<color>mediumturquiose</color>
</div>
<div name="seventeen">
<color>mistyrose</color>
</div>
<div name="eighteen">
<color>oldlace</color>
</div>
<div name="nineteen">
<color>olive</color>
</div>
<div name="twenty">
<color>azure</color>
</div>
</divcolors>
```

an example of the css:

```
#one {
border-radius: 300px;
background: blue;
position: absolute;
float: left;
top: 550px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-left:  500px;
margin-top: 5px;
z-index: 4;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier (.5,-5,.3,1.3), ease;
transition-delay: .2s;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    changeColors(xhttp);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "divcolors.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function changeColors(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var colorCrap= "";
var colorColor = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("color");
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
for (i=0; i<colorColor.length;i++){
    colorCrap += colorColor[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

}
x[i].style.backgroundColor = colorCrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but no cigar. You need to select the right element in the XML and get the value the proper way. There are several ways to solve this problem, and here I just did it based on your method.

I have made a working demo that you can be inspired from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>XML Color</title>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div class="div" id="one"><h1>1<br><br> <br>REQUIREMENT #1</h1></div>
  <div class="div" id="two"><h2>2</h2></div>    
  <div class="div" id="three"><h2>3</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="four"><h2>4</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="five"><h2>5</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="six"><h2>6</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="seven"><h2>7</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="eight"><h2>8</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="nine"><h2>9</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="ten"><h2>10</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="eleven"><h2>11</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="twelve"><h2>12</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="thirteen"><h2>13</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="fourteen"><h2>14</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="fifteen"><h2>15</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="sixteen"><h2>16</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="seventeen"><h2>17</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="eighteen"><h2>18</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="nineteen"><h2>19</h2></div>
  <div class="div" id="twenty"><h2>20</h2></div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="changediv" onclick="setTheColors()">
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
function changeColors(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var colorColor = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < colorColor.length; i++){
    var current = colorColor[i].getAttribute('name');
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(current);
    theDiv.style.backgroundColor = colorColor[i].childNodes[0].nextSibling.innerHTML;
}
}

function setTheColors(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        changeColors(xhttp);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "divcolors.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<divcolors>
<div name ="one">
    <color>aliceblue</color>
</div>
<div name ="two">
    <color>aquamarine</color>
</div>
<div name="three">
    <color>coral</color>
</div>
<div name="four">
    <color>cornflowerblue</color>
</div>
<div name="five">
    <color>cyan</color>
</div>
<div name="six">
    <color>darkgray</color>
</div>
<div name="seven">
    <color>darkolivegreen</color>
</div>
<div name="eight">
    <color>darkviolet</color>
</div>
<div name="nine">
    <color>deepskyblue</color>
</div>
<div name="ten">
    <color>forestgreen</color>
</div>
<div name="eleven">
    <color>honeydew</color>
</div>
<div name="twelve">
    <color>lightsalmon</color>
</div>
<div name="thirteen">
    <color>lightsteelblue</color>
</div>
<div name="fourteen">
    <color>maroon</color>
</div>
<div name="fifteen">
    <color>mediumspringgreen</color>
</div>
<div name="sixteen">
    <color>mediumturquiose</color>
</div>
<div name="seventeen">
    <color>mistyrose</color>
</div>
<div name="eighteen">
    <color>oldlace</color>
</div>
<div name="nineteen">
    <color>olive</color>
</div>
<div name="twenty">
    <color>azure</color>
</div>
</divcolors>
```